# Find the WAN adress for a customer (Linux console)

Tags: linux, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the Public IP address in a shell script](https://serverfault.com/questions/89114/finding-the-public-ip-address-in-a-shell-script)

I'm trying to problem solve a network Connection for a customer, and have to do a speed test on the network from Our Linux console. I'm not sure how I'll get the right WAN address.

I have the gw of the router, and the ip of the network for the ISP. Is it one of these ip that I should take a traceroute on?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the public IP from the console use curl

```
curl -s http://whatismyip.org/
```

or

```
curl -s checkip.dyndns.org|sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//'
```

To test the speed of your connection just download an ISO file from a random website.