# One-liner to retrieve external IP address

Tags: linux, scripting, ip-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the Public IP address in a shell script](https://serverfault.com/questions/89114/finding-the-public-ip-address-in-a-shell-script)

For use in scripting, it would be handy to be able to do this:

```
IP=`....something ....`
echo ...$IP... >> configfile
```

I'm looking for the IP address as seen by the web, in this instance. Ubuntu, if it makes a difference. Happy to install a package or two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
IP=`curl ifconfig.me`

[stephan@nemesis] ~ $ curl ifconfig.me
173.13.169.18
```

Voila. :)

(Edit Sept 2020)

I usually use icanhazip.com now.  You may need to chop the newline, though:

`curl -s icanhazip.com | tr -d '\n'`

Comment: I'd suggest, ifconfig.me returns (to curl) only the IP address without any header or body tags.