# How can I find my public ip address with built in system commands without relying on any third party websites or services?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line-interface

Are there any built in system commands such as ping that let me discover my public ip-address either on a Windows or Linux operating system?  This should not rely on any third party websites or services.

Comment: You cannot.  Didn't you see the other nearly identical question on the front page?  http://serverfault.com/questions/475445/one-liner-to-retrieve-external-ip-address

Comment: @Zoredache Thank you for the information with the link.  I have seen ways of using third party utilities.  I have figured out how to do it and will post the answer.

Comment: Several protocols, such as SMNP and UPnP, can be used to automatically query your router for its WAN-side IP address.  But, as @Grant mentions, this might not be the same as your external Internet-facing address.

Answer (score 8):

To tell what your public ip address appears to be to third parties you need a third party to tell you what they see.

If you don't want to rely on a third party...be the third party and have your own web server located somewhere else tell you.

Even if you can get the information from your router that may not always be what other systems see - you may be behind carrier NAT or an ISP proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

Before the packets reach the NAT device, there's not enough information to determine what the external IP address is going to appear as.  To answer your question, I'd log on to the ADSL modem (if that's what is supplying your internet connection and doing the NAT for you) and check the connection and see what IP address was assigned by the ISP.

If my assumptions accurately reflect your network setup, that IP address you see should be the address other hosts on your LAN appear to be when viewed from the Internet.

The config at my workplace is messy and has unnecessary bits... if I do a tracert, I don't see a hop with an IP address that matches what whatismyip.com reports is my IP address.