# Finding all Public IPv4 and IPv6 addresses in a UNIX shell script

Tags: load-balancing, ipv6, ip-address, ipv4, xargs

For monitoring purposes, I'd like to find out all public IPv4 and IPv6 addresses of a mobile-warrior UNIX box.

Note that this is different from [Finding the Public IP address in a shell script](https://serverfault.com/questions/89114/finding-the-public-ip-address-in-a-shell-script/560059#560059) because of the following extra requirements:

- the mobile warrior itself probably does not have any public IPv4 addresses at all;
- it may or may not have IPv6 (but we're only interested in active ones that would be used in actual outgoing connections);
- the underlying internet connection might be load-balanced, details unknown, where a combination of UDP, TCP, ICMP and source/destination IP address, may determine which upstream will be used; we need to try our best to find out all such IP addresses for a complete picture on the underlying internet connectivity of the gateway, without having direct access to the gateway itself.

Answer (score 5):

## Explanation

We can determine the [public IP address through DNS](//serverfault.com/questions/89114/finding-the-public-ip-address-in-a-shell-script/560059#560059) with [`dig`](http://mdoc.su/-/dig) (the DNS lookup utility from BIND), this lets us try out both UDP (with the `+notcp` option) and TCP  (`+tcp` option), leaving only ICMP behind.  However, we can try sending all these queries to multiple independent destination IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, making it more likely that the load-balancing of the connection will take place, returning more unique responses.

It would appear that the positioning of the `-4` and `-6` options with [`dig`](http://mdoc.su/-/dig) might also be handled differently depending on the order of the arguments — if positioned right after `dig` before the `@` specifier, then it's enforced as a hard requirement; if positioned past the `@` specifier and/or as a final argument, then it's enforced as a soft requirement (IPv4 will be used if IPv6 connectivity is missing); the snippet below uses it as a soft requirement to avoid having to implement error-handling.

We can use [GNU Parallel](http://ports.su/sysutils/parallel) to mix-and-match several commands and options that are at stake here.

## Solution

Here's the full solution:

```
parallel -kj16 dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short \
::: @ns{1,2,3,4}.google.com ::: -4 -6 ::: +notcp +tcp
```

Here's the same snippet as a single line:

```
parallel -kj16 dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short ::: @ns{1,2,3,4}.google.com ::: -4 -6 ::: +notcp +tcp
```

Here's the same snippet SO inline:

`parallel -kj16 dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short ::: @ns{1,2,3,4}.google.com ::: -4 -6 ::: +notcp +tcp`

---

## Testing

Here's a demonstration of what the above [`parallel`](http://ports.su/sysutils/parallel) invocation would work to accomplish:

```
% parallel -k echo dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short \
? ::: @ns{1,2,3,4}.google.com ::: -4 -6 ::: +notcp +tcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns1.google.com -4 +notcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns1.google.com -4 +tcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns1.google.com -6 +notcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns1.google.com -6 +tcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns2.google.com -4 +notcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns2.google.com -4 +tcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns2.google.com -6 +notcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns2.google.com -6 +tcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns3.google.com -4 +notcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns3.google.com -4 +tcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns3.google.com -6 +notcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns3.google.com -6 +tcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns4.google.com -4 +notcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns4.google.com -4 +tcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns4.google.com -6 +notcp
dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short @ns4.google.com -6 +tcp
%
```

---

## P.S. More of GNU Parallel

To extend on our solution above, the following could be used to perform whois and rDNS lookups on all found addresses; note that for IPv6 lookups to work on BSDs and macOS, one might have to specify `-a` for ARIN, `-A` for APNIC or `-r` for RIPE as an option to [`whois`](http://mdoc.su/-/whois):

`parallel -kj16 dig -t txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com +short ::: @ns{1,2,3,4}.google.com ::: -4 -6 ::: +notcp +tcp | sort -n | uniq | parallel -vk ::: "echo" "host" "whois -a" :::: /dev/stdin`

Comment: `:::: /dev/stdin` can also be written `:::: -` which will also work on systems that do not support `/dev/stdin`.